# Copy row with many fields by trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I've a table with 48 columns. So it's almost impossible (or let it be) to write a trigger like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl_trigger_update
AFTER update ON tbl1
FOR EACH ROW
update tbl2 set v1=NEW.v1, v2=NEW.v2, ... v48=NEW.v48 where id=old.id
```

but I dont want to write something like above.
I want to fire a trigger on update/insert on tbl1 to copy/update rows to tbl2
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is tbl2 a child table of tbl1?  Does data in tbl2 get inserted/updated /deleted outside of tbl1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something with the `insert ... select` syntax. [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) is the docs of the statement.